# Google Map v2 wont locate me

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So i was making something location related in one pc and everything used to work fine. Then after a day the app could not locate me when i was using the mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); method. Then i moved the whole project to a new pc and reinstalled everything and the problem persists. I deployed the apk in two different phones and to a friend's one. Everything worked for the friend but both my phones had an issue.

Anyone have any clue? (API key is fine, i can see the map. It just won't locate me.

Code:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is    not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // ---if Google Play services is available---
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successful" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        //---Google Play services was not available for
        // some reason---
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"shit" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }


    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
        if(mMap != null){
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
        }
    }
};

}
```

Comment: it sounds like hardware problem. If it is working on phone A but not working on phone B. Check if the gps signal is ok

Comment: GPS in both phones work fine. In fact when i use the Maps app from google itself it locates me pretty fast. Not on my app though.

Comment: I would recommend to debug `loc` in `onMyLocationChange`. You will see then do you receive any updates

Comment: You can download and try and sample project [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android), and plz tell me the result:)